# Removed N rows containing missing values BUT there are no missing values nor values out of range

Tags: r, ggplot2

I posted a similar question a week ago but I failed to identify the real problem. Therefore, the question was far from being correct.

Now, I clearly now what is going on but I cannot understand why it is happening. I also reviewed similar problems related with the same error but the solutions for these problems were not applicable to my case.

I am plotting the frequency distribution of a variable during the fieldwork progress of a survey. Therefore, it shows how the proportion of that variables has changed through time.

So, I have a variable (Startday) that tells which day the respondent took the survey, if he/she did not then it is NA. Then, I have the typical variables like sex or marital status.

This is the code to plot such graph

```
    df %>% 
  mutate(date = lubridate::mdy(startday)) %>% 
  arrange(date) %>% 
  mutate(Rs = cumsum(sf_sex %in% c("Male", "Female")),
         female_Rs = cumsum(sf_sex == "Female")) %>% 
  group_by(date) %>% 
  slice(n()) %>% 
  select(date, Rs, female_Rs) %>% 
  mutate(female_prop = female_Rs/Rs) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = female_prop)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

And this is what I get.

[image]

Exactly what I want. The problem comes when I am using Marital status as a variable (and that variable has the same nature than the other: dummy and character). This is what I get using the following code:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(date = lubridate::mdy(startday)) %>% 
  arrange(date) %>% 
  mutate(Rs = cumsum(Maritaldummy %in% c("Not married", "Married")),
         Married_Rs = cumsum(Maritaldummy == "Married")) %>% 
  group_by(date) %>% 
  slice(n()) %>% 
  select(date, Rs, Married_Rs) %>% 
  mutate(Married_prop = Married_Rs/Rs) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = Married_prop)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

[image]
Followed by this error:

Warning messages:
1: Removed 34 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
2: Removed 34 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path).

As you can see the observations stop around the 5th of June.

Things to consider:

- It is not out of range as I tried change the graph's range using ylim() and xlim()
- There are no missing values

The strange part comes when this code works for experimental groups 2 and 3 (n = 350 each one) but not for experimental group 1 (n= 2050). I do believe the error has to come from here as when I random sample less than 1300 observations for group 1... it works!!! This is an example of the same code for group 2.

[image]

I am giving you a reproducible example but I am afraid the error only works when using it with the full sample but maybe you discover what is wrong with it?

Thanks a lot for the attention, time & help.

```
df <- structure(list(startday = c("06/02/2019", "05/22/2019", "05/28/2019", 
                            "05/26/2019", "06/03/2019", "06/10/2019", "05/22/2019", "05/30/2019", 
                            "05/31/2019", "06/18/2019", "05/22/2019", "05/25/2019", "05/25/2019", 
                            "05/22/2019", "06/14/2019", "06/14/2019", "05/20/2019", "05/27/2019", 
                            "05/20/2019", "05/21/2019", "05/20/2019", "05/20/2019", "06/09/2019", 
                            "06/12/2019", "05/24/2019", "05/20/2019", "05/20/2019", "05/28/2019", 
                            "06/09/2019", "05/20/2019", "06/21/2019", "06/03/2019", "06/07/2019", 
                            "05/26/2019", "05/28/2019", "06/03/2019", "06/06/2019", "06/05/2019", 
                            "05/27/2019", "06/10/2019", "05/20/2019", "06/05/2019", "05/20/2019", 
                            "06/04/2019", "05/23/2019", "05/20/2019", "06/11/2019", "05/28/2019", 
                            "06/09/2019", "06/15/2019", "05/25/2019", "06/14/2019", "05/20/2019", 
                            "06/05/2019", "06/04/2019", "06/10/2019", "06/16/2019", "06/05/2019", 
                            "06/29/2019", "05/30/2019", "06/03/2019", "06/09/2019", "05/20/2019", 
                            "05/25/2019", "06/16/2019", "06/14/2019", "05/21/2019", "05/28/2019", 
                            "06/09/2019", "06/07/2019", "05/25/2019", "05/20/2019", "05/27/2019", 
                            "05/20/2019", "05/21/2019", "05/20/2019", "06/17/2019", "06/26/2019", 
                            "06/07/2019", "05/22/2019", "06/19/2019", "06/04/2019", "05/21/2019", 
                            "05/21/2019", "05/21/2019", "06/14/2019", "05/25/2019", "06/19/2019", 
                            "05/20/2019", "06/03/2019", "05/20/2019", "06/04/2019", "05/20/2019", 
                            "05/27/2019", "05/22/2019", "05/20/2019", "06/02/2019", "05/21/2019", 
                            "05/23/2019", "06/03/2019", "06/14/2019", "06/14/2019", "06/07/2019", 
                            "05/20/2019", "05/23/2019", "06/24/2019", "06/03/2019", "05/20/2019", 
                            "06/06/2019", "06/15/2019", "06/06/2019", "05/27/2019", "05/24/2019", 
                            "05/22/2019", "05/20/2019", "05/30/2019", "06/23/2019", "05/21/2019", 
                            "05/20/2019", "06/16/2019", "05/20/2019", "05/24/2019", "05/21/2019", 
                            "05/21/2019", "06/20/2019", "05/20/2019", "05/22/2019", "06/06/2019", 
                            "05/20/2019", "05/21/2019", "06/15/2019", "05/27/2019", "05/26/2019", 
                            "06/06/2019", "05/20/2019", "06/05/2019", "06/02/2019", "06/20/2019", 
                            "05/22/2019", "05/20/2019", "06/03/2019", "05/20/2019", "06/03/2019", 
                            "05/20/2019", "06/03/2019", "05/22/2019", "05/20/2019", "05/22/2019", 
                            "05/22/2019", "05/20/2019", "05/20/2019", "05/23/2019", "05/23/2019", 
                            "05/23/2019", "06/05/2019", "06/08/2019", "06/03/2019", "05/24/2019", 
                            "06/05/2019", "06/02/2019", "05/20/2019", "05/29/2019", "06/04/2019", 
                            "05/21/2019", "06/08/2019", "06/12/2019", "05/30/2019", "06/05/2019", 
                            "06/12/2019", "05/20/2019", "05/20/2019", "06/26/2019", "05/20/2019", 
                            "06/04/2019", "05/20/2019", "06/06/2019", "05/24/2019", "05/24/2019", 
                            "06/06/2019", "06/22/2019", "05/26/2019", "05/29/2019", "05/27/2019", 
                            "05/20/2019", "05/23/2019", "05/21/2019", "05/22/2019", "05/22/2019", 
                            "06/11/2019", "06/05/2019", "06/05/2019", "05/28/2019", "05/23/2019", 
                            "06/13/2019", "05/20/2019", "06/07/2019", "05/28/2019", "06/12/2019", 
                            "06/28/2019", "06/15/2019"), sf_sex = c("Female", "Male", "Male", 
                                                                    "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
                                                                    "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
                                                                    "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", 
                                                                    "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", 
                                                                    "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", 
                                                                    "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", 
                                                                    "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", 
                                                                    "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
                                                                    "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", 
                                                                    "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", 
                                                                    "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", 
                                                                    "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
                                                                    "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", 
                                                                    "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
                                                                    "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", 
                                                                    "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", 
                                                                    "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", 
                                                                    "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", 
                                                                    "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", 
                                                                    "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
                                                                    "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", 
                                                                    "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", 
                                                                    "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", 
                                                                    "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", 
                                                                    "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", 
                                                                    "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", 
                                                                    "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", 
                                                                    "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male"), Maritaldummy = c("Not married", 
                                                                                                                                               "Married", "Married", "Not married", "Not married", "Married", 
                                                                                                                                               "Married", "Married", "Not married", "Not married", "Not married", 
                                                                                                                                               "Married", "Married", "Married", "Married", "Married", "Not married", 
                                                                                                                                               "Not married", "Not married", "Married", "Not married", "Not married", 
                                                                                                                                               "Not married", "Not married", "Not married", "Married", "Married", 
                                                                                                                                               "Not married", "Married", "Not married", "Married", "Not married", 
                                                                                                                                               "Not married", "Not married", "Not married", "Not married", "Married", 
                                                                                                                                               "Not married", "Married", "Married", "Not married", "Not married", 
                                                                                                                                               "Married", "Not married", "Married", "Not married", "Not married", 
                                                                                                                                               "Not married", "Married", "Married", "Married", "Not married", 
                                                                                                                                               "Not married", "Married", "Married", "Not married", "Not married", 
                                                                                                                                               "Married", "Married", "Not married", "Married", "Married", "Married", 
                                                                                                                                               "Not married", "Married", "Not married", "Not married", "Married", 
                                                                                                                                               "Not married", "Married", "Not married", "Not married", "Not married", 
                                                                                                                                               "Married", "Not married", "Not married", "Married", "Married", 
                                                                                                                                               "Not married", "Married", "Married", "Married", "Married", "Married", 
                                                                                                                                               "Married", "Not married", "Married", "Not married", "Not married", 
                                                                                                                                               "Not married", "Not married", "Not married", "Married", "Not married", 
                                                                                                                                               "Married", "Married", "Not married", "Not married", "Married", 
                                                                                                                                               "Not married", "Married", "Married", "Married", "Married", "Not married", 
                                                                                                                                               "Married", "Married", "Married", "Not married", "Married", "Not married", 
                                                                                                                                               "Not married", "Married", "Not married", "Married", "Not married", 
                                                                                                                                               "Not married", "Married", "Not married", "Married", "Not married", 
                                                                                                                                               "Married", "Married", "Not married", "Married", "Married", "Married", 
                                                                                                                                               "Not married", "Married", "Married", "Married", "Married", "Married", 
                                                                                                                                               "Married", "Married", "Married", "Not married", "Not married", 
                                                                                                                                               "Not married", "Married", "Married", "Married", "Not married", 
                                                                                                                                               "Married", "Not married", "Married", "Not married", "Married", 
                                                                                                                                               "Married", "Married", "Married", "Married", "Not married", "Married", 
                                                                                                                                               "Not married", "Not married", "Married", "Married", "Married", 
                                                                                                                                               "Married", "Married", "Married", "Married", "Married", "Not married", 
                                                                                                                                               "Married", "Married", "Married", "Not married", "Not married", 
                                                                                                                                               "Married", "Not married", "Married", "Not married", "Married", 
                                                                                                                                               "Married", "Not married", "Not married", "Married", "Not married", 
                                                                                                                                               "Married", "Not married", "Not married", "Married", "Not married", 
                                                                                                                                               "Not married", "Married", "Married", "Married", "Not married", 
                                                                                                                                               "Not married", "Not married", "Married", "Married", "Married", 
                                                                                                                                               "Married", "Not married", "Not married", "Married", "Not married")), row.names = c("3564", "2999", "20144", "17281", "11917", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "14549", "5116", "10553", "23108", "19521", "277", "24312", "5449", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "19006", "9171", "21265", "20494", "11961", "15556", "12237", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "10959", "23460", "14050", "13996", "16222", "21852", "5593", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "18871", "18770", "776", "24913", "7813", "25079", "1063", "22878", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "13638", "19169", "7226", "14895", "8088", "19789", "22835", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "14196", "13816", "7124", "10394", "8290", "16807", "732", "3130", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "16033", "14958", "7500", "15039", "1538", "12532", "2890", "18907", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "21581", "3120", "20198", "22943", "8468", "3128", "24153", "22911", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "6225", "8489", "13040", "17506", "14855", "1500", "11955", "24484", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "17625", "19888", "10351", "19210", "22946", "14699", "1959", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "6770", "23286", "11842", "12811", "22197", "5899", "10138", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "20505", "16090", "17835", "20512", "12271", "9152", "12767", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "25244", "16865", "6970", "10036", "22531", "12329", "15366", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "2", "9440", "2100", "23166", "11421", "18912", "4441", "25202", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "20599", "411", "12584", "1586", "4543", "1307", "10044", "25033", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "5005", "25122", "16236", "9653", "16194", "14393", "7512", "10059", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "12010", "1619", "3136", "24088", "14641", "19564", "9568", "18815", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "21079", "22010", "9553", "20380", "20416", "15745", "7000", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "7735", "24924", "15286", "20403", "4680", "13714", "13302", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "12508", "17514", "4480", "7446", "3723", "24069", "25317", "14607", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "12274", "21715", "8983", "23488", "9228", "7265", "18192", "16475", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "11760", "15530", "18177", "11535", "18839", "17908", "9789", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "18045", "1025", "21645", "11853", "22453", "18052", "22763", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "9", "12286", "15329", "3306", "13215", "16533", "18385", "23784", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "10131", "4894", "14154", "3365", "8648", "17325", "21219", "16689", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "9969", "10621", "24206", "19621", "8440", "19889"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I just edited with the code

Comment: What does `sum(is.na(df$Maritaldummy))` return in your original data?

Comment: It gives 2....
May the problem be that the values cannot be computed because of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can reproduce the error if you change any one value to `NA` in the column.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df$Maritaldummy[195] <- NA

df %>% 
  mutate(date = lubridate::mdy(startday)) %>% 
  arrange(date) %>% 
  mutate(Rs = cumsum(Maritaldummy %in% c("Not married", "Married")),
         Married_Rs = cumsum(Maritaldummy == "Married")) %>% 
  group_by(date) %>% 
  slice(n()) %>% 
  select(date, Rs, Married_Rs) %>% 
  mutate(Married_prop = Married_Rs/Rs) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = Married_prop)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

Returns

> Warning messages:
> 1: Removed 38 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
> 2: Removed 38 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path).

Since one or more than one value is `NA` `cumsum` fails and returns `NA` for all the values after that. An easy fix is to use `%in%` instead of `==` which returns `FALSE` when compared to `NA`.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(date = lubridate::mdy(startday)) %>% 
  arrange(date) %>% 
  mutate(Rs = cumsum(Maritaldummy %in% c("Not married", "Married")),
         Married_Rs = cumsum(Maritaldummy %in% "Married")) %>% 
  group_by(date) %>% 
  slice(n()) %>% 
  select(date, Rs, Married_Rs) %>% 
  mutate(Married_prop = Married_Rs/Rs) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = Married_prop)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```